# Functions satisfying the functional equation $ \big( 1 - f ( x ) f ( y ) \big) f ( x + y ) = f ( x ) + f ( y ) $

Tags: functions, continuity, functional-equations

How can I prove that there is no real function defined on $ \mathbb R $, continuous at $ 0 $ and not always vanishing satisfying the functional equation
$$ \big( 1 - f ( x ) f ( y ) \big) f ( x + y ) = f ( x ) + f ( y ) \text ? \tag E $$

Comment: $$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y}$$

Comment: Which is not defined on whole $\mathbb R$

Comment: One could say it _is_ defined on all of $\mathbb R$, and takes the value $\infty$ at certain points, and this is neither $+\infty$ nor $-\infty$ but rather the $\infty$ that is approached by going in either direction along the line, and all this has the effect of making the function everywhere continuous including at those points where its value is $\infty$.  BUT the question said "real function", which means its values are in $\mathbb R$. So this function doesn't do it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Since the tangent function has vertical asymptotes, I would start by looking at the question of how to prove that this functional equation entails that there must be vertical asymptotes. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy That is what I'm trying to do... but having hard time for the time being! Up to now, I'm able to prove that $f$ is continuous everywhere and vanishing only at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no doubt established $f(0)=0$.

Suppose such an $f$ is not bounded above. Then for all $x_0$ with $f(x_0)>0$, there exists a $y_0$ with $f(y_0)=\frac{1}{f(x_0)}$. And then the relation gives  $0=f(x_0)+f(y_0)$, a contradiction.

So such an $f$ must be bounded above. (Similarly, it must be bounded below.)

If $f$ ever reaches an output of $1$, then the relation gives $0=2$, so the supreumum of $f$'s outputs, $S$,  is at most $1$.

Assume $f$ takes some positive values. Let $X$ be an $x$-value such that $f(X)$ is $\epsilon S$ where $\epsilon$ is some number slightly smaller than $1$. We know that $0<\epsilon S<1$.  Then using $x=y=X$, the relation gives that $$f(2X)=\frac{2f(X)}{1-f(X)^2}=\frac{2(\epsilon S)}{1-(\epsilon S)^2}>2\epsilon S>S$$ a contradiction.

So $f$ takes no positive values. Similarly, it takes no negative values. $f$ would have to be the zero function.

---

Note that if $f$ is allowed to spike to $\pm\infty$, then this argument fails where we claim that $\left[1-f(x_0)f(y_0)\right]f(x_0+y_0)=f(x_0)+f(y_0)$ yields a contradiction. In that scenario, $f(x_0+y_0)=\pm\infty$ would offer a way out.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a solution.

I use what @Mathcounterexample.net has found, i.e that the function verify $f(0)=0$, $f(x)\not =0$ if $x\not =0$ and that it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Replace $x$ by $y$ in the functional equation, we get $\displaystyle (1-f(x)^2)f(2x)=2f(x)$. Now if there exist $x$ such that $f(x)^2=1$, we have $x\not = 0$, and $f(x)=0$, a contradiction. Hence $f(x)^2\not =1$ for all $x$. As $f$ is continuous, we must have $(f(x))^2>1$ for all $x$ or $(f(x))^2<1$ for all $x$. But $f(0)=0$; hence we have $(f(x))^2<1$ for all $x$. Now on $[0,+\infty[$, we must have $-1<f(x)\leq 0$ or $0\leq f(x)<1$. Replacing $f$ by $-f$ if necessary, one can suppose that $0\leq f(x)<1$ for all $x\geq 0$. Let $M={\rm Sup}\{f(x), x\geq 0\}$. We have $\displaystyle 2f(x)=(1-f(x)^2)f(2x)\leq M$, hence $f(x)\leq M/2$. This imply $M\leq M/2$, and $M=0$, hence $f=0$ on $[0,+\infty[$. As $f$ is odd, we have $f=0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Letting $x=y=0$, we get that $f(0)=0$.

Letting $y=-x$, we get that $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

If for some $x$ and $y$, we have $f(x)f(y)=1$ then $f(x)+f(y)=0$ which leads to a contradiction. So for all $x$ and $y$, $f(x)f(y)\ne1$. By $f(-x)=-f(x)$, we also have $f(x)f(y)\ne-1$.

Substituting $x+h$ for $x$ and $-x$ for $y$ in the original equation, we have $f(x+h)-f(x)=\big(1+f(x)f(x+h)\big)f(h)$. Now, because $f$ is continuous at $0$, so for positive $\epsilon$, there exists a positive $\delta$ such that if $|h|<\delta$ then $|f(h)|<\frac\epsilon{|1+f(x)f(x+h)|}$, which shows that $f$ is continuous at every point.

Now, because $f$ is continuous at every $x$, $1-f(0)^2=1>0$ and $1-f(x)^2\ne0$, so we have $1-f(x)^2>0$, or equivalently $|f(x)|<1$, for every $x$. But by letting $y=x$ in the original equation, we get $|f(2x)|=\Big|\frac{2f(x)}{1-f(x)^2}\Big|\ge2|f(x)|$. By induction, we have $|f(2^nx)|\ge2^n|f(x)|$, for every positive integer $n$. This shows that if there is a point $x$ such that $f(x)\ne0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $|f(2^nx)|>1$, which leads to a contradiction. So the only solution to the functional equation is the constant zero function, which you've ruled out.