# Real-valued function solving $f(x+y)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{1-f(x)f(y)}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a real valued differentiable function of a single variable s.t $$f(x+y)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{1-f(x)f(y)},$$ $\forall x,y$ with $f(x)f(y)$ is not equal to $-1$ & $f(0)=0.$ Then prove that $f(t)=\tan(gt)$, $g$ being a constant.

Comment: Did you mean to have a recursive definition for $f(x)$?

Comment: $\tan gt$ is not even continuous, let alone differentiable.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question. I also changed the title so as to better reflect the question.

Comment: You mean $f(x)f(y) \ne 1$

Comment: Related: [Functions satisfying the functional equation $ \big( 1 - f ( x ) f ( y ) \big) f ( x + y ) = f ( x ) + f ( y ) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1551712/229831).

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$f(x+y)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{1-f(x)f(y)} \tag{1}$$

We note that $f$ is odd; since

\begin{align*}
f(x-x) = \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{1 - f(x) f(-x)} &\Rightarrow f(0) = \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{1 - f(x) f(-x)}\\ 
 &\Rightarrow f(x) + f(-x) =0 \\ 
 &\Rightarrow f(-x) = - f(x)
\end{align*}

Since $f$ is differentiable the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f \left ( x_0 + h \right ) - f(x_0)}{h} \\ 
 &=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{f(x_0) + f(h)}{1-f(x_0)f(h)} - f(x_0)}{h} \\ 
 &=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{f(x_0) + f(h) - f(x_0) \left ( 1 - f(x_0) f(h) \right )}{1-f(x_0) f(h)}}{h} \\ 
 &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0) + f(h) - f(x_0) + f^2(x_0) f(h)}{h\left ( 1 - f(x_0) f(h) \right )} \\
 &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h) + f^2(x_0) f(h)}{h \left ( 1 - f(x_0) f(h) \right )} \\
 &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h) \left ( 1 + f^2(x_0) \right )}{h \left ( 1 - f(x_0) f(h) \right )} \\
 &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} \cdot \frac{1 + f^2(x_0)}{1 - f(x_0) f(h)} \\
 &= f'(0) \left ( 1 + f^2(x_0) \right )
\end{align*}

Therefore ,

$$f'(x) = f'(0) + f’(0) f^2(x) \quad \forall x $$

The last differential equation is classical. Can you take it from here?